# How to scrape specific words from the scrolling web table?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to scrape ticker symbol from the table and check for if certain keywords are present{"GD","Daily price"," TSI"} in the "final settlement price" row. In the table, there are multiple dynamic columns.
Below is one example:
I want to scrape ticker Symbol of "Ambuja Cements Futures" which is "ZACE" and store it in the list and also check if certain keywords are present in the "Final settlement Price" row.
[image: A you can see in the image ZACE]

[image: After Scrolling down to the table, You can see Final settlement price row]

Here is the HTML code for the ticker symbol row:

```
<tr>
   <th>Ticker Symbol</th>
   <td>ZADS</td>
   <td>ZACE</td>
   <td>ZAPN</td>
   <td>ZARB</td>
   <td>ZAXS</td>
   <td>ZBJA</td>
   <td>ZBAF</td>
   <td>ZBPC</td>
   <td>ZBHA</td>
   <td>ZBHI</td>
   <td>ZBOS</td>
   <td>ZCIP</td>
   <td>ZCOA</td>
   <td>ZDRR</td>
   <td>ZEIM</td>
   <td>ZGAI</td>
   <td>ZHCL</td>
   <td>ZHDB</td>
   <td>ZHMC</td>
   <td>ZHND</td>
   <td>ZHPC</td>
   <td>ZHUV</td>
   <td>ZHDF</td>
   <td>ZICI</td>
   <td>ZIHF</td>
   <td>ZIOC</td>
   <td>ZIIB</td>
   <td>ZINF</td>
   <td>ZITC</td>
   <td>ZKMB</td>
   <td>ZLT</td>
   <td>ZLPC</td>
   <td>ZMM</td>
   <td>ZMSI</td>
   <td>ZNTP</td>
   <td>ZONG</td>
   <td>ZPWG</td>
   <td>ZRIL</td>
   <td>ZSBI</td>
   <td>ZSUN</td>
   <td>ZTCS</td>
   <td>ZTTM</td>
   <td>ZTAT</td>
   <td>ZTEC</td>
   <td>ZUTC</td>
   <td>ZUPL</td>
   <td>ZVED</td>
   <td>ZWPR</td>
   <td>ZYES</td>
   <td>ZZEE</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the HTML code for the Final settlement price row:

```
<tr>
   <th>Final Settlement Price</th>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.
      <br>
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.
      <br>
   </td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.
      <br>
   </td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
   <td>The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.</td>
</tr>
```

You can visit website for the same: https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS

Comment: Can you please properly indent the HTML in your question? You can find online HTML formatters that make this quick and easy.

Comment: Please also add the python code you are usingg to scrape the text.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Here. I updated the HTML code. But, Because of word limit, I can't upload full code. You can see by clicking the link of the website. I tried with the selenium to scrap this, But couldn't succeed. So if you can provide me the solution, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the table is loaded dynamically so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. But you can use `re`/`json`/`requests` module to get the data:

```
import json
import re
import requests


url = 'https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS'

app_config_url = 'https://www.sgx.com/config/appconfig.js'
n = re.search(r"apiVersion: '(.*?)'", requests.get(app_config_url).text).group(1)
variables = '''{{"path":"/derivatives/products/{}","lang":"EN"}}'''.format( url.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1] )
url2 = 'https://api2.sgx.com/content-api?queryId={}:page&variables={}'.format(n, variables)

data = requests.get(url2).json()

# uncomment this to prin all data:
#print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for c in data['data']['route']['data']['data']['contracts']:
    if c['data']['title'] == 'Ambuja Cements Futures':
        print(c['data']['tickerSymbol'])
        print(c['data']['finalSettlementPrice'])
```

Prints:

```
ZACE
The Final Settlement Price for the Contracts will be the official closing price of the Underlying Shares on the Last Trading Day, rounded to 2 decimal places, expressed as US dollars.
```

---

EDIT: New version after site update:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/products/indiassf?cc=ZADS'

config = requests.get('https://www.sgx.com/config/appconfig.json').json()

variables = '''{{"path":"/derivatives/products/{}","lang":"EN"}}'''.format( url.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1] )
url2 = 'https://api2.sgx.com/content-api?queryId={}:page&variables={}'.format(config['cms']['apiVersion'], variables)

data = requests.get(url2).json()

# # uncomment this to prin all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for c in data['data']['route']['data']['data']['contracts']:
    if c['data']['title'] == 'Ambuja Cements Futures':
        print(c['data']['tickerSymbol'])
        print(c['data']['finalSettlementPrice'])
```

Comment: I think the answer should not have been posted in this case. because, it reinforces the concept that "SO is a free code problem solving website". This Q shows no sign of minimal reprex nor any research effort.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Hey this code was running fine until I checked today. It gives an error. " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' " . Looks like website had a maintenance update. Since I just started learning json, I don't know how to get app_config_url. So if you can help me out, I will be thankful. Also If you can share any source of learning json.

Comment: @chintanpatel See my update. About JSON: That's just exchange format, similar to Yaml or XML. I would start with HTTP/HTML protocols - how the web works (requests, http headers), regular expressions, CSS selectors etc.